# python pip install finder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

[image: demo]

So As you can see in the above pic I like to document what library requirements are needed to run this script.
(mostly for when I move the script to another computer or upload it to someone else)
But my problem is not all imports match the name of there pip install command, key example here being BeautifulSoup.
So I would like to know if there is a python command to look up a library name from it's import.
Like hay, tell me what packadge this import is from kinda thing.
Bonus: As you can see in the project we are using lxml with BeautifulSoup so we don't need to import it, but it does need to be installed. Is there a "thing" that I can just chuck a py script at and it will tell me what requirements I need to run it.
I know that pyinstaller for example will package all the librarys it needs to make the exe, I wonder if there is a way I can run pyinstaller in like an info mode.
**Edit:** I don't want to build a requirements.txt for the hole computer, just one for the script i'm working on currently.
Or just requirements.txt for *only one py file*, not the hole computer.

Comment: make a `requirements.txt` file, that is what requirements files are for.

Comment: Are you looking for (the output of) `pip freeze`?

Comment: Correct way of doing this is using a requirements.txt file. If however you need the package name of a specific module, this only works the other way around. Go through the `.dist-info` folders inside your side-packages and read the content of `top_level.txt` this file contains the name of the importable module for a package. Just loop through the folders until you find the one you are looking for. Again: There are better ways for your use case, but this comment appears to be the only one actually answering the question.

Comment: Yeah @Tim Woocker I didn't want to build a requirements file for the hole computer, just the script i'm working on.

Comment: @MobCat In that case the right way would be to create a virtual environment. Then you can use the requirements.txt only for a specific project: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pipreqs` library ([from pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/)) is used to collect imported libraries for the *specific program* and export to a `requirements.txt` file.

Using `pip freeze` exports *all* installed libraries and is generally not ideal for project based `requirements.txt` files.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to solve that is by creating a `requirements.txt` file:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then you can add it to version control (or simply copy over to another computer) and:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Which will install all the packages listed on the file into the new environment.

Comment: Ok yes, this dumps all the librarys installed on my computer. I don't want all of them, just the ones that relate to this script i'm working on. can I point freeze at a specific script file?

Comment: The `pipreqs` library (from pypi) is used to collect imported libraries for the specific program and export to a `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: **Note:** This will export *all* installed libraries for the given environment and not ideal for project based requirements files.

Answer (score 1):

You should define the requirements for a script to run in a so called [requirements file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/). The [search](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_search/) command provided by pip may be what you are looking for. But there is no reliable way to reverse lookup package names just based on their import name. Your modus operandi should be:

1. Determine what packages you need
2. Add needed packages into `requirements.txt` file
3. Install the dependencies (preferably within a virtual environment or similar) via `pip install -r requirements.txt`

If you put the requirements file into version control along with your script others can profit from your work much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to S3DEV
[pipreqs](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/) worked.
`pipreqs C:\MyProjectFolder`
Will make a requirements.txt for only the python files in the MyProjectFolder folder and only the scrips in that folder, not the hole computer.
It will save the requirements.txt to the same folder.
Also sorry for being new here, but this was a sub comment and I don't know how to "give the points" for solving my issues to S3DEV. So I'll just mark this one as solved...

Comment: Excellent, glad it was helpful.   I’ll pop a proper answer on, if you’d like to accept.